# R Shiny for loop

Tags: r, shiny

I have problem with my R shiny code. I don´t know how do create a double for loop in shiny with values who are typed in by the user. It says: "Error in <-: incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix"
BTW: Is shiny the right package for me when i just want do create an app for user inputs?

```
shinyServer(
function(input, output){


sum1 <- reactive(input$sum1)
weight1 <- 0.7
weight2 <- 1-weight1

asset1 <- reactive({sum1()*weight1})

asset2 <- reactive({sum1()*weight2})



counter1 <-  reactive(input$counter1)
counter2 <- reactive(input$counter2) 

for (j in 1:counter1) {
  start <- reactive(sum1())
  for (i in 1:counter2) {
    start <- reactive({asset1()*asset2*rnorm(1, mean <- 0, sd <- 1)})
    value1[j] <- start
}

   result1 <- quantile(value1, c(0.01))
   output$result1 <- value1

 }
  )



library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel(title = "Simulation"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(("Data"),
           numericInput("sum", "sum:", 0, min=0, max=1000000),
           numericInput("counter1", "counter1", 0, min=0, max=1000),
           numericInput("counter2", "counter2", 0, min=0, max=1000),

           submitButton("submit")),

mainPanel(("Results:"),
         textOutput("result1"), 



         )

 )

))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `counter1` and `counter2` need to be invoked with parentheses. Also, `start`. Not sure defining a reactive function in a for loop works as I have never tried it, but you can check.

Comment: @user3949008 Sorry I can´t understand your comment. Can you provide an example for my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a few problems: extra commas, unclosed brackets.. I think the missing bracket at the `shinyServer` is the reason why your server wasn't responding to the user.

Another thing is that you passed all your `input`s to `reactive`s. You can use you `input` values directly. And as @user3949008 said, I don't know if you can define a `reactive` in a loop. Here is one possible code:

```
server<-shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    weight1 <- 0.7 
    weight2 <- 1 - weight1

    asset1 <- reactive({ input$sum * weight1 })
    asset2 <- reactive({ input$sum * weight2 })

    output$result <- renderText({
      for (j in 1:input$counter1) {
        start <- input$sum
        for (i in 1:input$counter2) {
          start <- asset1() * asset2() * rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1)
          value1 <- start
        }
        result1 <- quantile(value1, c(0.01))
        outputresult1 <- value1
      }
      paste("Results:", outputresult1)
    })
  }
)

library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title = "Simulation"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        "Data",
        numericInput("sum", "sum:", 0, min=0, max=1000000),
        numericInput("counter1", "counter1:", 0, min=0, max=1000),
        numericInput("counter2", "counter2:", 0, min=0, max=1000)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("result")
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```